# How to make many nested property objects quickly with less lines?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

so I'm using mongoDB for a migration project which takes queries as plain javascript/JSON:

```
queryObj = {}; // our main object I pass to mongodb for queries
```

The below code throws error

```
queryObj[inObj.row]['$eq'] = inObj.equals;
```

but this works....

```
queryObj[inObj.row[i]] = {};
queryObj[inObj.row]['$eq'] = inObj.equals;
```

Is there a easy way to make a object with many nested properties sans having to define them as object? I could make a constructor function but I assuming their is an easy in-built solution via Object.create.

Comment: There's not an easy way to use dot notation with chained properties, without first creating the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to create a method that will create empty objects if needed.

```js
/**
 * Sets a deep property on an object by creating any required
 * objects in the hierarchy that may not yet exist
 * @param {object} obj The object to receive properties
 * @param {string} prop Dot separated deep property to set
 * @param {*} value What to set the given property to
 */
function setProp(obj, prop, value) {
  var parts = prop.split('.');
  var i = 0;

  for (; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
    if (typeof obj[parts[i]] === 'undefined') {
      obj[parts[i]] = {};
    }
    obj = obj[parts[i]];
  }
  // Note that parts[i] is pointing to the last part of the deep property name
  // and obj points to the nested object that contains the last deep property
  obj[parts[i]] = value
}

   
var obj = {}
setProp(obj, 'a.b.c', 3);

console.log(obj.a.b.c); // 3
```

For your case you could so something like

```
setProp( queryObj, inObj.row + ".$eq", inObj.equals );
```